# Embedding live video stream to a html5 webpage; both camera server and webserver hosted on pi

Tags: camera, web-server, html5

I have a USB camera connected to my pi. I'm also hosting my personal website on it. How do I create a separate page on my website with authentication and display the live feed from my port 8081 on it?

Comment: Welcome to RPi.SE. Have you looked at motion ? You might need to work on authentication part though. Here's a good tutorial on how to setup motion on RPi. http://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-webcam-server/

Comment: Hi. I did use motion to serve that feed on my_ip:8081. Now I want to show the output on that port to a webpage.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't quite get your previous comment. Can you elaborate what is working currently and what you want to implement ? I believe if motion is running, you should be able to view the feed on browser on <your-ip>:8081. I believe that it worked on firefox and not on chrome when I tried it a long time ago.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Everything's working now, the camera feed is on port 8081 and my website on port 80. Now I want to embed my video feed on a webpage on my website "xyz.com/cam.html" (behind a login page preferebly). Then my friends in another country can view my feed with just the login details and without needing my IP address (which is dynamic)
Can this be done?

Comment: Ok, I'm not an expert on the subject but I believe motion transmits in motion jpeg format and this link (the last part) : https://blog.clipchamp.com/2015/how-to-play-back-mjpeg-animated-gif-and-mp4-video-on-web-sites/ shows how mjpeg feed can be embedded to the web page. I haven't tried it but it should work. Hope it helps.

Comment: Or may be simply have a look at it. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14740/live-video-streaming-embedded-in-a-web-page looks like a very simple solution.

Comment: Thanks for the links. The first link doesn't work for my live feed. The second works (!) but only when accessed from a computer in my network. That makes sense since I used <img src=192.168.1.4:8081/?action=stream/>

Comment: How are you connecting RPi on internet ? I assume it must be having an IP address or DDNS url ? The easiest solution would be : using <rpi-url:8081> in your code and makes sure that you forward that port on your router.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. My raspberry pi has the local IP 192.168.1.4. Is that what you meant by rpi-url? My Pi connects through a wireless usb adapter to the home network.